# foreach bind value `Invalid parameter number` php pdo

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, foreach

I have a foreach bind value and i always get `Invalid parameter number: number of bound variables does not match number of tokens` even if i have same number of parameters i am guessing it has something to do with my for each so i will post my foreach code.Below is my foreach code for inserting in database. Hoping for constructive comments.

```
foreach($material as $item) {
    $stmt7 = $dbh - > prepare("INSERT INTO material_tbl (id,floorone,floortwo,floorthree,floorfour,wallone,walltwo,wallthree,wallfour,roof) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)");
    $stmt7 - > bindValue(1, $id, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    foreach($item as $key => $value) {
        if ($key === 'floor 1st Floor') {
            echo "1st floor mat= ".
            "$value\n";
            $stmt7 - > bindValue(2, $value, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        } else if ($key === 'floor 2nd Floor') {
            echo "2nd floor mat= ".
            "$value\n";
            $stmt7 - > bindValue(3, $value, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        } else if ($key === 'floor 3rd Floor') {
            echo "3rd floor mat= ".
            "$value\n";
            $stmt7 - > bindValue(4, $value, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        } else if ($key === 'floor 4th Floor') {
            echo "4th floor mat= ".
            "$value\n";
            $stmt7 - > bindValue(5, $value, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        } else if ($key === 'wall 1st Floor') {
            echo "2nd wall floor mat= ".
            "$value\n";
            $stmt7 - > bindValue(6, $value, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        } else if ($key === 'wall 2nd Floor') {
            echo "2nd wall floor mat= ".
            "$value\n";
            $stmt7 - > bindValue(7, $value, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        } else if ($key === 'wall 3rd Floor') {
            echo "3rd wall floor mat= ".
            "$value\n";
            $stmt7 - > bindValue(8, $value, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        } else if ($key === 'wall 4th Floor') {
            echo "4th wall floor mat= ".
            "$value\n";
            $stmt7 - > bindValue(9, $value, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        } else if ($key === 'roof') {
            echo "roof mat= ".
            "$value\n";
            $stmt7 - > bindValue(10, $value, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        }
        $stmt7 - > execute();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem that this line

```
$stmt7 - > execute();
```

Is inside the foreach loop. You should first initialize ALL the bindValues and then use the execute.

**edit:** To be more specific how to fix in your code:

```
 foreach(....) {
 ....
 } else if ($key === 'roof') {
            echo "roof mat= ".
            "$value\n";
            $stmt7 - > bindValue(10, $value, PDO::PARAM_STR);
  }
}
$stmt7->execute();
....
```

As you see - OUT OF LOOP.

Comment: and how do you suggest i do it sir?